# Не могу запустить проект на symfony! Пожалуйста помогите

Tags: php, symfony

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in C:\xampp\htdo
>   cs\Ninjaz\vendor\doctrine\annotations\lib\Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Annotation
>   Registry.php on line 50

Comment: Напишите версию php которую используете, а также версию symfony которую планируете установить.

Comment: В аннотациях где-то накосячил.

Answer (score 0):

В php7 появились хинты типов возвращаемого результата:

```
function a(): int {return 5;}
```

Видимо в Вашей версии php этот синтаксис не является валидным.
Обновите php или используйте совместимые версии symfony/doctrine